# Pointwise derivative in differential geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry

Once we define the operator $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}})_{p}$ to be the element of the tanget space such that $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}})_{p} :f \rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{k}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial e_{k}}(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$

is it acceptable to think of the image as a function of p and consider this to be the derivative of $f$ defined for $p$,pointwise defined on $U$ with $x$  the local chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This line of thought will lead you to consider vector fields as maps on $C^\infty(M)$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds) (read from: An alternative definition...).